# Image full screen with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how CSS3 and jQuery work together for an image gallery and I am stuck in this situation:

I have a page like this: http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/gallery2.html
I got the first part right, when I have to load the large image and switch from one to another with this code.

I have the thumbnails to the left and the main image to view to the right like this:

```
<div id="thumbsBox">
    <img id="one" src="tn/image-01.jpg" alt="first" class="blurredThumb"/>
    <img id="two" src="tn/image-02.jpg" alt="second" />
    <img id="three" src="tn/image-03.jpg" alt="third" />
    <img id="fourth" src="tn/image-04.jpg" alt="fourth" />             
</div> 

<div class="largeImage">
    <img src="lg/image-01.jpg" alt="first" />
</div>
<p id="fullscreen"> Here full screen</p>
```

This is the CSS used:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
}

#thumbsBox {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 300px;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#thumbsBox img {
    float: left;
}

.largeImage { 
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    border:  1px solid #333333;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.largeImage img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.blurredThumb {
    opacity: 0.7;
}


#thumbsBox img:hover {
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fullscreen {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $('#thumbsBox img').click (function() {
        $(".largeImage img").attr('src', this.src.replace('tn','lg'));
    });

    $("#fullscreen").click (function() {
        $("#thumbsBox").css('display', 'none');
        $(".largeImage").addClass('fullscreen');
    });
});
```

It's working as described when I have to change the image, but I cannot figure out properly how to make a selected image "full screen".
Any tip is welcome. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake this is the correct one

Comment: what is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your solution. Check please:

```js
$(document).ready (function(){


 $('#thumbsBox img').click (function() {

  $(".largeImage img").attr('src', this.src.replace('tn','lg'));



 });



 $("#fullscreen").click (function() {

  $("#thumbsBox").css('display', 'none');

  $(".largeImage").addClass('fullscreen');
  
   

 });


});
```

```css
body {
 
margin: auto;

}


#thumbsBox {

float: left;
margin-top: 300px;
width: 220px;
padding: 0px;

}

#thumbsBox img {

float: left;


}



.largeImage { 


width: 900px;
height: 600px;
border:  1px solid #333333;
float: right;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-top: 100px;
 

}

.largeImage img { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
 

}


.blurredThumb {

 opacity: 0.7;

}


#thumbsBox img:hover {

float: left;

 opacity: 0.7;
}

.fullscreen {

 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbsBox">
    <img id="one" src="http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/tn/image-01.jpg" alt="first" class="blurredThumb">
    <img id="two" src="http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/tn/image-02.jpg" alt="second">
    <img id="three" src="http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/tn/image-03.jpg" alt="third">
    <img id="fourth" src="http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/tn/image-04.jpg" alt="fourth">
</div>
    <div class="largeImage">
        <img src="http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/lg/image-03.jpg" alt="first">
    </div> 
     <p id="fullscreen"> Here full screen</p>
```

Comment: or you'll need that after click on thumbnail picture wide on full screen?

Comment: If Full screen image, you can try: 

html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Hi ALex. i need that (setting the selected image of the gallery full screen, if I want) as an option clicking on "Here full screen".  sorry for thequestion, but in the case you suggested, i am setting a background image. can i use that also for the images of a photogallery?